# Sending push notifications to Android devices using Parse

Tags: c#, android, api, push-notification, parse-platform

I find the parse documentation is little confusing when it comes to Android. I am sending notifications using Parse from a .NET background service. The service is calling Parse REST API

- Install the device with `deviceToken` and `deviceType`
- Send push notification to device once the previous step is successful.

This works beautifully with iOS device
POST: `1/push`

```
{  
    "deviceToken": "<big device token>",
    "deviceType": "android",
    "channels" : []
}
```

This says

```
{
    code: 114
    error: "deviceToken may not be set for deviceType android"
}
```

the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-updating) says, we need to have a unique `installationId` for Android device install uploads. How do I do this from backend? Which API should be used to get installation Id?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get the installation ID :

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId()
```

([Class Reference](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseInstallation.html#getInstallationId%28%29))

Comment: Push is happening from server side and using .NET. The libraries parse have are client side libraries. That's why I am using REST API deliver notifications. But it's great to know what is meant by `getInstallationId()` and how it's wrapped under the hood

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, Parse doesn't support android device installations using REST API; it supports from client side SDK.

https://www.parse.com/questions/android-device-installation-via-rest